# App crashes when endless list view is srcrolled

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have a fragment class in which i am loading listview data using asynctask.
Once the user reaches end of the scroll i need to load the another set of data i am doing this.

```
 listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                if (userListAdapter == null)
                    return;

                if (userListAdapter.getCount() == 0)
                    return;

                int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
                if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
                    // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
                    listView.addFooterView(footer);
                    isLoading = true;
                    listener.loadData();
                }
            }
        });
```

i get callback in loaddata here

```
 @Override
    public void loadData() {
        if (connection != null) {
             connection.getmService().new FetchJsonData().execute(Constants.WEEK_URL1);
        }

    }
```

**my adapter code.**

```
    public class UserListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<UserInfoModel> userInfoModelArrayList;

    public UserListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserInfoModel> userInfoModelArrayList) {
        this.userInfoModelArrayList = userInfoModelArrayList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return userInfoModelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return userInfoModelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent,false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            viewHolder.userName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            viewHolder.userID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userID);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.userName.setText(userInfoModelArrayList.get(position).getUserName());
        viewHolder.userID.setText(userInfoModelArrayList.get(position).getUserID());
        return convertView;
    }


    public void setFilter(ArrayList<UserInfoModel> informationArrayList) {
        userInfoModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        userInfoModelArrayList.addAll(informationArrayList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<UserInfoModel> informationArrayList) {
        userInfoModelArrayList.addAll(informationArrayList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView userName;
        TextView userID;
    }
}
```

But my app crashes once it reaches first set of data i have added progressbar at the footer of listview.

Error log

```
02-19 18:45:09.757 3114-3114/example.service.android.santosh.com.androidservice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                  Process: example.service.android.santosh.com.androidservice, PID: 3114
                                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getImportantForAccessibility()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1876)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:666)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5060)
                                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4608)
                                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Please help Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace as well. ? That would help a lot in order to identify the issue.

Comment: sure i will give me a sec

Comment: Please post code related to getImportantForAccessibility method i.e how you are calling it and the method itself.

Comment: Where did you initialise your Layout Inflater ? Ideally, it should be inside the getView() .

Comment: it is initialized in constructor of adapter.

Comment: Mr Rabbit there is no method called getImportantForAccessibility

Comment: Initializing  Layout Inflater not really a issue i have tried in getview() method not working still crashes

Comment: Try to replace convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,null); with convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, null);

Comment: convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent,false); i tried this convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, null); will not really work third parameter needs boolean value. still crashing

Comment: Hmm. please post your full adapter code and other code related to adding new items asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue this issue was not related to adpater it was due to adding footer view in the on scroll of listview footer view is supposed to be added on create of fragment.

**onCreate**

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.loading_view, null, false);
        listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

**onScroll**

```
if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
                    // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
                    isLoading = true;
                    listener.loadData();
                }
```

it solves my problem. BTW thank you all :)

Comment: Ah ! Right, you were attaching the footerView inside onScroll(). Damm i shouldn't have missed that. Anyways, Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ...

```
MyViewHolder viewHolder = null;

if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewHolder = new MyViewHolder();;
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_brands_layout_search, null);
        viewHolder.imageOne = (DynamicHeightImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_brand_pinrest_view);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
 viewHolder= (MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
 }
```

This should be the ideal way to write an adapter.

Comment: Not helping bro still same crash.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with your getCount() or getItemId(int pos). Could you please post the adapter code to get more things clear. ?